# In Angular JS Kendo Drop down not setting the model value

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-dropdown

HI I have following Kendo Dropdown, even though I have a value in ng-model, the dropdown is not selecting the default values.

```
<select name="myDropDown"
                                id="myDropDown"
                                class="width-90"
                                kendo-drop-down-list k-data-text-field="'key'"
                                k-data-value-field="'value'"
                                k-data-source="myDataSource"
                                ng-model="model.selectedProperty"></select>
```

model.selectedProperty does have the value . However the UI does't select the options.

DataSource Values:

```
[{"key":"Critical","value":0},{"key":"High","value":1},{"key":"Medium","value":2},{"key":"Low","value":3}]

model.selectedProperty = 1
```

The above one should have selected the second option, but the dropdown selects none

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have to make the selected value same object as in the list:

`$scope.model.selectedProperty = {"key":"Critical","value":0}`

And I updated the select tag to,

```
<select name="myDropDown"
                                id="myDropDown"
                                class="width-90"
                                ng-model="model.selectedProperty"
                                ng-options="option.key for option in myDataSource track by option.value">
                        </select>
```